# Esp32 INPUT-pullup

Tags: esp8266, esp32, pullup

I have an enable pin that i want to drive high always except when a limit switch is closed, and at the same time I want to monitor the state of the limit switch So is that possible with input_pull-up mode on esp32 pins?
[image: INput pull-up]

Comment: Is there a reason you've chosen to defy convention and draw everything upside-down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the question, is it possible, it certainly is possible and that's why internal pull-ups exist, to keep a pin high if nothing is driving it.

However, for your specific application, we can't know if a pull-up will work in your case.

Pull-ups are quite weak, and if there is a long cable between a limit switch and the MCU, the pull-up resistance may be too weak. It might be that if you touch the IO pin even with a finger, the MCU may detect the pin toggling at mains frequency.

Flipping a light switch nearby could also cause the MCU to see a pulse.

So preparing with a real external pull-up which is much lower in resistance could be a good idea.

Comment: After trial your answer is perfectly accurate, the internal pull provided only 1.8 volts at the pin which was not enough to drive any pin high

Comment: @hjeij2000 That is impossible. An internal pull-up should be able to pull a pin to a definite logic high level without problems. Either there is a problem somewhere, or your button/switch is not a button/switch that leaves a pin floating but something else.